# Invalid Grant error while access Workbench

Tags: workbench

I used to have Workbench access but when I changed my laptop, It seems the access is lost. However, I am still able access through SoqlExplorer.
What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

**To resolve the "invalid grant" error while accessing Salesforce Workbench:**
1.Double-check your login credentials and ensure they are correct.
2.Refresh your OAuth token by logging out and logging in again.
3.Append your security token to your password when logging in.
4.Make sure your laptop's IP address is whitelisted in Salesforce.
5.Verify that your user profile has the necessary permissions for Workbench access.
6.Clear your browser's cookies and cache or try a different browser.